# por que me sale esta exception y no carga los datos en el textbox?

Tags: c#

```html
1   ADMINISTRADOR   2024-02-07 15:56:07.907
2   EMPLEADO    2024-02-12 13:33:52.030
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas con c# y sql, guiandome por un tutorial de youtube, sin embargo, tengo dos errores que no he podido solucionar y creo que estan relacionados
PRIMER ERROR:  es que cuando ejecuto mi programa se cae por una excepcion, lo que quiero es que los nombres de las columnas del grid se muestren en el combobox de busqueda, sin embargo, si comento el select index=0 no se cae la ejecucion y me muestra el despliegue del combobox.

```cs
  private void frmUsuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     cmboxEstado.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = 1, texto = "Activo" });
     cmboxEstado.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = 0, texto = "No Activo" });
     cmboxEstado.DisplayMember = "texto";
     cmboxEstado.ValueMember  = "Valor";
     cmboxEstado.SelectedIndex = 0;

     List<Rol> listaRol= new CapaNegRol().Listar();
     foreach (Rol item in listaRol)
     {
         cmboxRol.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = item.IdRol, texto = item.Descripcion });
     }
     cmboxRol.DisplayMember = "texto";
     cmboxRol.ValueMember = "Valor";
     cmboxRol.SelectedIndex = 0;

     foreach (DataGridViewColumn columnaaa in datagridDatos.Columns)
     {
         if (columnaaa.Visible == true && columnaaa.Name != "btnSeleccionar") {
             cmboxBusqueda.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = columnaaa.Name, texto = columnaaa.HeaderText });
         }
         cmboxBusqueda.DisplayMember = "texto";
         cmboxBusqueda.ValueMember = "Valor";
         ***cmboxBusqueda.SelectedIndex = 0; //AQUI SALE LA EXCEPCION***
     }

     //para mostrar todos los usuarios
     List<Usuario> listaUsuario = new CapaNegUsuario().Listar();
     foreach (Usuario item in listaUsuario)
     {
         datagridDatos.Rows.Add(new object[] {"", item.IdUsuario, item.Documento ,  item.NombreCompleto, item.Correo, item.Clave,
  item.objRol.IdRol, item.objRol.Descripcion, item.Estado==true ?1:0, item.Estado==true ? "Activo": "No Activo" });
     }
     
 }

 private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     datagridDatos.Rows.Add(new object[] {"", txtboxid.Text ,  txtboxDocumento.Text, txtboxNombreCom.Text, txtboxCorreo.Text, txtboxClave, 
  ((OpcionCombo)cmboxRol.SelectedItem).Valor.ToString(), ((OpcionCombo)cmboxRol.SelectedItem).texto.ToString(), 
     ((OpcionCombo)cmboxEstado.SelectedItem).Valor.ToString(), ((OpcionCombo)cmboxEstado.SelectedItem).texto.ToString()});
 }
```

[![excepcion que arroja][1]][1]

[![base de datos de Rol del trabajador][2]][2]
[![se deberia mostrar aqui sin comentar el select index][3]][3]

SIGUIENTE ERROR(SUPONGO QUE ESTA RELACIONADO)
al momento de querer que los datos del usuario seleccionado se muestren en el cuadro de textboxs del lado izq. (nombre completo, documento, correo....) no se reflejan al momento de hacer click en el btnSeleccionar.
[![error numero 2][4]][4]

```cs
 private void datagridDatos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
     if (datagridDatos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "btnSeleccionar")
     {
         int indice = e.RowIndex;
         if(indice > 0)
         {
             txtboxid.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
             txtboxDocumento.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["NroDocumento"].Value.ToString();
             txtboxNombreCom.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["NombreCompleto"].Value.ToString();
             txtboxCorreo.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["Correo"].Value.ToString();
             txtboxClave.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["Clave"].Value.ToString();
             txtboxconfirmarClave.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["ConfirmarClave"].Value.ToString();
         }
     }
     
 }
```

a continuacion agrego el codigo completo

```cs
 public partial class frmUsuarios : Form
 {
     public frmUsuarios()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void frmUsuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         cmboxEstado.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = 1, texto = "Activo" });
         cmboxEstado.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = 0, texto = "No Activo" });
         cmboxEstado.DisplayMember = "texto";
         cmboxEstado.ValueMember  = "Valor";
         cmboxEstado.SelectedIndex = 0;

         List<Rol> listaRol= new CapaNegRol().Listar();
         foreach (Rol item in listaRol)
         {
             cmboxRol.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = item.IdRol, texto = item.Descripcion });
         }
         cmboxRol.DisplayMember = "texto";
         cmboxRol.ValueMember = "Valor";
         cmboxRol.SelectedIndex = 0;

         foreach (DataGridViewColumn columnaaa in datagridDatos.Columns)
         {
             if (columnaaa.Visible == true && columnaaa.Name != "btnSeleccionar") {
                 cmboxBusqueda.Items.Add(new OpcionCombo() { Valor = columnaaa.Name, texto = columnaaa.HeaderText });
             }
             cmboxBusqueda.DisplayMember = "texto";
             cmboxBusqueda.ValueMember = "Valor";
             //cmboxBusqueda.SelectedIndex = 0; AQUI SALE LA EXCEPCION
         }

         //para mostrar todos los usuarios
         List<Usuario> listaUsuario = new CapaNegUsuario().Listar();
         foreach (Usuario item in listaUsuario)
         {
             datagridDatos.Rows.Add(new object[] {"", item.IdUsuario, item.Documento ,  item.NombreCompleto, item.Correo, item.Clave,
      item.objRol.IdRol, item.objRol.Descripcion, item.Estado==true ?1:0, item.Estado==true ? "Activo": "No Activo" });
         }
         
     }

     private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         datagridDatos.Rows.Add(new object[] {"", txtboxid.Text ,  txtboxDocumento.Text, txtboxNombreCom.Text, txtboxCorreo.Text, txtboxClave, 
      ((OpcionCombo)cmboxRol.SelectedItem).Valor.ToString(), ((OpcionCombo)cmboxRol.SelectedItem).texto.ToString(), 
         ((OpcionCombo)cmboxEstado.SelectedItem).Valor.ToString(), ((OpcionCombo)cmboxEstado.SelectedItem).texto.ToString()});
     }

     private void datagridDatos_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.RowIndex < 0)
             return;
         if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
         {
             e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

             var w = Properties.Resources.check.Width;
             var h = Properties.Resources.check.Height;
             var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
             var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

             e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.check, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
             e.Handled   = true;
         }
     }

     private void datagridDatos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {
         if (datagridDatos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "btnSeleccionar")
         {
             int indice = e.RowIndex;
             if(indice > 1)
             {
                 txtboxid.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
                 txtboxDocumento.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["NroDocumento"].Value.ToString();
                 txtboxNombreCom.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["NombreCompleto"].Value.ToString();
                 txtboxCorreo.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["Correo"].Value.ToString();
                 txtboxClave.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["Clave"].Value.ToString();
                 txtboxconfirmarClave.Text = datagridDatos.Rows[indice].Cells["ConfirmarClave"].Value.ToString();
             }
         }
         
     }
 }
```

en SQL los rol estan asignados y con datos

Comment: Que quieres decir con new OpcionCombo?

Comment: foreach (Rol item in listaRol)  Está seguro que hay algo en listaRol?